# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "586cc8b3ea780c071bbe2469" at path "_id" for model "User"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I saw a couple of post with similar to mine but I still getting the same error

here is my user schema

```html
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  local: {
    email: String,
    password: String,
  },
});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

my routes

```html
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
});

router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
  res.render('signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
});

router.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  res.render('profile.ejs', { user: req.user });
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/signup',
  failureFlash: true,
}));

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true,
}));

module.exports = router;

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
      return next();
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

my app.js

```html
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');


var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({ secret: 'shhsecret' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

require('./config/passport')(passport);


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

And here is my passport.js Im using local passport

```html
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

  passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true,
  },
  function(req, email, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      User.findOne({ 'local.email':  email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            return done(err);
        if (user) {
          return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already in use.'));
        } else {
          var newUser = new User();
          newUser.local.email = email;
          newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
          newUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
              throw err;
            return done(null, newUser);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }));

  passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true,
  },
  function(req, email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ 'local.email':  email }, function(err, user) {
      if (err)
          return done(err);
      if (!user)
          return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));
      if (!user.validPassword(password))
          return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Wrong password.'));
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }));
};
```

passport works it save the user to the database

```html
expressauth 5 > db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("586cc8b3ea780c071bbe2469"), "local" : { "password" : "$2a$08$vANw7GJIk8RUVEpJWnwSpOVQ77RuHCjbXiGoQVl.Fx/thhbMkEVWu", "email" : "david@david.com" }, "__v" : 0 }
expressauth 6 >
```

Cast to ObjectId failed for value “586cc8b3ea780c071bbe2469” at path “_id” for model “User”

I have built a couple apps that use passport oauth the exact same way that I have displayed above. So I dont know why Im getting this error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem with `mongoose` version > 4.7.2

Problem is about [bson](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/issues/204) package.

I solved it with installing an older version of mongoose.

`npm install mongoose@4.7.2`

or you can change package.json to use exact version 4.7.2 `"mongoose": "4.7.2"`

You can update to newer versions after the problem is solved. You can track it on [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4860).

Answer (score 4):

The error exists in your `serializeUser` function in `passport`.

**You need to use `user._id` instead of `user.id`**.

since there is no `field` as `id` in your `UserSchema`, `user.id` will be`undefined`, and while `deserializing` the user, `undefined` is not `typeOf` `ObjectId`, thus it is throwing above error.

**Try this:**

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
  });
```

**Update:**

Do this in your `deserializeUser`:

cast the upcoming `id` to `ObjectId`, just to be sure, and then use that `ID` to `query` the `User`.

```
var userId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(id);
User.findById(userId , function(err, user) {
   done(err, user);
});
```

Dont forget to include `mongoose` in the same file.

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
```

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: I made that user._id update and im still getting the same error.But the error is being made at deserializingUser function.

Comment: Can you tell me what `console.log(id)` prints, in `deserializeUser`?

Comment: the id that gets printed out in deserializeUser is the same id that gets displayed when i get an error  “586cc8b3ea780c071bbe2469”.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Did you try to cast in into an object ID?, Just like I showed in the update

Comment: changing the mongoose version to 4.7.2 worrked for me thanks for the help.

Comment: I had the same issue. moving to 4.7.2 worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to latest version of mongoose, you have to use `findOneAndRemove` instead of `FindByIdAndRemove`.

That is cast `objectId` problem.