# Mongoose refuses to cast valid string to ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, casting, objectid

I return the Document `_id` and use it as a `req.params.id` to get the document at a later stage.

`ObjectId.isValid()` returns `true`, then using it in either `ObjectId()` or `Find` or `FindOne` will result in a cast error or

> hex is not a function.

Basically also copy pasted the `_id` straight from the database to test.

I'm using mongoose *^4.7.6*; `_id` looks like: `586e30a597f85b69891df304`

> [Stack trace]
>
> [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value
>   "586e30a597f85b69891df304" at path "_id" for model "Module"]
>         message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "586e30a597f85b69891df304" at path "_id" for model "Module"',
>         name: 'CastError',
>         stringValue: '"586e30a597f85b69891df304"',
>         kind: 'ObjectId',
>         value: '586e30a597f85b69891df304',
>         path: '_id',
>         reason: undefined,

Comment: "hex is not a function" does not sound like Mongoose refuses to cast. It sounds more like a bug either in your or somebody else's code. Please post the whole stacktrace of the error.

Comment: added part of the trace, though cant seem to format correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast to ObjectId failed for value "586cc8b3ea780c071bbe2469" at path "\_id" for model "User"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461562/cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-586cc8b3ea780c071bbe2469-at-path-id-for-m)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a bug in Mongoose >=4.7.3
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4867

bson package is really buggy

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a bug in that version of mongoose. Removing my node_modules and reinstalling with mongoose set to 4.3.3 fixed this issue.