# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model "Coach"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

My app works locally, but in production I can't seem to fetch a specific thing from mongo using mongoose. I've tried:

`var Coach = mongoose.model('Coach', CoachSchema);`

- `Coach.findOne({ _id: req.session.userId}, function (err, coach) {})`
- `Coach.find({ _id:req.session.userId}, function (err, coach) {})`
- `Coach.findById(req.session.userId).exec(function(err, coach)){})`

I've received the same error: 
`Cast to ObjectId failed for value "586bc06bd09d870012baa5b8" at path "_id" for model "Coach"`

Like I said, it works locally with both `nodemon` and `heroku local` but on my heroku production server it doesn't work.

I've read a little about this type of cast error here:

- [What's Mongoose error Cast to ObjectId failed for value XXX at path "_id"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940660/whats-mongoose-error-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-xxx-at-path-id)
- [Mongoose refuses to cast valid string to ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485198/mongoose-refuses-to-cast-valid-string-to-objectid)
- [Cast to ObjectId failed for value "586cc8b3ea780c071bbe2469" at path "_id" for model "User"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461562/cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-586cc8b3ea780c071bbe2469-at-path-id-for-m)

But no luck yet. Any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast to ObjectId failed for value "586cc8b3ea780c071bbe2469" at path "\_id" for model "User"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461562/cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-586cc8b3ea780c071bbe2469-at-path-id-for-m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced this same issue sometimes back, for `mongoose` version > 4.7.2

I solved it by installing `mongoose` version 4.7.2

```
npm install mongoose@4.7.2
```

also, you can change your `package.json` so that it uses this exact version of mongoose.

```
"mongoose" : "4.7.2"
```

This bug is caused because of `bson` package. which gives the error

> **Hex is not a function on ObjectId creation**

Read more about it in [this](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/issues/204) link.

This bug started when `mongoose` was updated from version `4.7.2` to `4.7.3`.
You can update to newer version of `mongoose` when this bug is solved. You can track the bug [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4860) and [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4867).

**So, Finally you can solve this error by installing mongoose version 4.7.2**